# magnitude $\cot(z)$ for large $|z|$

Tags: complex-analysis

**Context**

This question regards the evaluation of sums using periodic functions in a product. I am having difficulty understanding the basis for the same. Here are two interrelated questions that I believe will help my  conceptual understanding.

**Question**

(1) How can I show that $\cot {z}$ has magnitude of order 1 for large $|z|$ when not extremely close to one of its poles?

(2) How can I show that $\cot {z}$ does not affect the limiting behavior of $\oint f(z)\,\cot{(z)}\,dz$?

**My attempts at a solution**

Part 1.

I start with a product expansion.

\begin{align*}
\cot{(\pi\,z)}
&=
\frac{\cos {\pi\,z}}{\sin \pi\,z}
\\
&=  
\frac
{
\prod_{n = 1}^\infty\left(1 - \frac{(\pi\,z)^2}{\pi^2\left(n - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2}\right) 
}
{
 \pi\,z  \prod_{n = 1}^\infty\left(1 - \frac{(\pi\,z)^2}{\pi^2 n^2}\right)
} 
\\
&=  
\frac
{
\prod_{n = 1}^\infty\left(1 - \frac{z^2}{ \left(n - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2}\right) 
}
{
 \pi\,z  \prod_{n = 1}^\infty\left(1 - \frac{  z ^2}{  n^2}\right)
} 
\\
&=  
\frac
{
\prod_{n = 1}^\infty\left(   
\left[ \left(n - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 - z^2\right]\,n^2\right) 
}
{
 \pi\,z  \prod_{n = 1}^\infty\left(     \left[n^2 -  z ^2\right]\left(n - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \right)
} 
\\
&=  
\frac
{
\prod_{n = 1}^\infty\left(   
\left[ n^2\,\left(n - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2\right] -  n^2\,z^2\right) 
}
{
 \pi\,z  \prod_{n = 1}^\infty\left(     \left[n^2\,\left(n - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \right]-  \left(n - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \,z ^2\right)
} 
\end{align*}
I argue (this seems like hand waiving to me---maybe because I do not know how to deal with competing infinities) that for any $n$ that I consider, I can write $z$ as, for example $e^{i\phi}\,n^n$,
Now, I write $z = R\,e^{-i\phi}$
\begin{align*}
&=  
\frac{1}{ \pi\,z }
\prod\limits
_{n = 1}^\infty
\frac
{
\left(   
n^2\,\left[ \left(n - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 -   R^2\,\left[\cos^2{\theta} - \sin^2{\theta} \right]\right] - i\,2\, n^2\,R^2\,\cos\theta\,\sin\theta \right) 
}
{
  \left(n - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2    \left[n^2  
 -      R^2\,\left[\cos^2{\theta}- \sin^2\theta  \right]
 \right]-    i\,2\,\left(n - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \,   R^2\, \cos\theta\,\sin\theta 
} 
\\\\
&=  
\frac{1}{ \pi\,z }
\prod\limits
_{n = 1}^\infty
\frac{n^2 }{  \left(n - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2}
\sqrt
{
\frac
{
\left[ \left(n - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 -   R^2\,\left[\cos^2{\theta} - \sin^2{\theta}  \right]\right]^2 + \left[2 \,R^2\,\cos\theta\,\sin\theta\right]^2
}
{
\left[ \left(n \right)^2 -   R^2\,\left[\cos^2{\theta} - \sin^2{\theta}  \right]\right]^2
+ \left[2 \,R^2\,\cos\theta\,\sin\theta\right]^2
}
}
e^\theta
\end{align*}

I think this is handwaiving, but here goes. I think of a particular $n$ for the moment, and pick $R$ to be much much bigger. If you want a larger $n$---say on the order of my $R$,---then I pick one still larger. Then,
\begin{align*}
&=  
\frac{1}{ \pi\,z }
\prod\limits
_{n = 1}^\infty
\frac
{
\left(   
n^2\,\left[ \left(n - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 -   R^2\,\left[\cos^2{\theta} - \sin^2{\theta} \right]\right] - i\,2\, n^2\,R^2\,\cos\theta\,\sin\theta \right) 
}
{
  \left(n - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2    \left[n^2  
 -      R^2\,\left[\cos^2{\theta}- \sin^2\theta  \right]
 \right]-    i\,2\,\left(n - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \,   R^2\, \cos\theta\,\sin\theta 
} 
\\\\
&=  
\frac{1}{ \pi\,z }
\prod\limits
_{n = 1}^\infty
\frac{n^2 }{  \left(n - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2}\,R^2
e^\theta
\end{align*}

NOT WORKING. TRY SOMETHING ELSE

\begin{align*}
\cot \theta = i\, \frac{e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta}}{e^{i\theta} - e^{-i\theta}} 
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\cot z = i\, \frac{e^{iz} + e^{-i\theta}}{e^{iz} - e^{-iz}} 
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\cot z = i\, \frac{e^{+i\, \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \left[\frac{x+ i\,y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \right]  } + e^{-iz}}{e^{iz} - e^{-iz}} 
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\cot z = i\, \frac{e^{+ix - y} + e^{-ix +y }}{e^{+ix - y} - e^{-ix +y }} 
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\left.\cot z\right|_{y=0} = i\, \frac{e^{+ix } + e^{-ix  }}{e^{+ix } - e^{-ix }} 
\end{align*}

NOT WORKING. SEEK HELP

Part 2.

I have no idea, but assume that an application of Jordan's lemma is in order.

Comment: Hi @Michael Levy, are you trying to prove a useful sum technique regarding the residue of $f(z)\cdot cot(z)$?

Comment: I meant the technique demonstrated in here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem#An_infinite_sum

Comment: @Udi Fogiel. Yes, I am trying to prove that useful technique found in the wikipedia page you mentioned. I find it very difficult to go forward unless I can understand the proof. Any thoughts for a more detailed proof?

Comment: In  en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem#An_infinite_sum, the part that I most struggle with is "The left-hand side goes to zero as $N\to\infty$ since the integrand has order $ O(n^{-2})$"